# I got a script to remotely load js files, is there a way to make it retry\wait on errors?

Tags: javascript

Here is the script i got:

```
loadScriptFromUrl = function(url) {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
script.async = false;
script._url = url;
document.body.appendChild(script); 
};
```

Is there a way to make it wait until the script is loaded? And\or retry to load it after a while if url returns an error? (Sometimes the remote heroku server goes idle so it returns an error and I have to launch it again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check If script is loaded or not, you can do it by adding `script.onload=function(){...}` .

***must note*** '- the `script.onload`  must come before script.src

Your code, with onload function

```
loadScriptFromUrl = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    script.onload=()=>{
        console.log("script loaded")
        //whatever you want to do
    }
    script.async = false;
    script.src = url;
    script._url = url;

};
```

If you want to check for any error on loading you can go with `script.onerror=function(){...}`

It will also come before script.src

```
loadScriptFromUrl = function(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    script.onerror=()=>{
        console.log("script not loaded")
        //reload script like below
        loadScriptFromUrl(url);
        //or reload the whole window by location.reload() method
    }
    script.async = false;
    script.src = url;
    script._url = url;

};
```

If you want to wait until the function loads the script you can put this function under an async function, add await keyword before it and return a promise resolve under script.onload();

E.g.

```
async function parentFunct(){
loadScriptFromUrl =await function(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    script.onload=()=>{
        console.log("script loaded")
        resolve();
    }
    script.async = false;
    script.src = url;
    script._url = url;
  })
};
}
```

The above code will stop everything inside parentFunc() until the script is loaded
Read more about js promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: the last one with the async function returns: 
"ReferenceError: loadScriptFromUrl is not defined" :(

Comment: You have to call it from inside the parentFunct(). I have just given a suggestion to use async/await, but if the problem still exists again tell me please as I am now on an android and unable to test. By the way sorry for the error.  Are other snippets working right?

Comment: Yes I've been able to fix it by on.load and on.error: re-load! Thank you!